# Matplotlib commands not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Whenever I run any matplotlib commands that plots/scatters a graph, it stops working, and the python console will run forever. If that line is in some script then the script runs forever.

Even simple code like `plt.plot([1,2,3,4])` doesn't work.

The backend is also set as 'TkAgg'

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python version is 3.5.2

Comment: Probably buggy installation of Python, or MatPlotLib?

Comment: Have you tried setting the backend to something else?

Comment: What platform are you on? Which Python version? How did you install?

Comment: Have you added plt.show() to display your graph?

Comment: yes I've added plt.show(). The code gets stuck on the plot() function. I'm using the default Python3 ver 3.5.2 which comes with Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

tr this and let me know if it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

Comment: doesn't work it keeps on running. The code gets stuck on `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`